# matching whitespace seems to be non-greedy

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-re

I'm writing a small helper script to analyse C code, especially the use of structs. I have problems detecting when a struct is used as a value as opposed to a pointer. That means I want to detect if the text `struct foo` is followed by an arbitrary amount of whitespace and a character that is not `*`.

I boiled my problem down to this MWE:

```
>>> import re
>>> there = re.compile('struct foo(\\s*)[^*]')
>>> match = there.search('struct foo *bar')
```

*Note. I need to use the double backslash because I cannot use raw strings in my application. I actually need an f-string.*

The MWE **should not produce a match** in my book. However, it does and if I look at `match.groups()`, I get

```
>>> match.groups()
('',)
```

meaning that `\\s*` did match zero whitespace characters. From the documentation I would have expected it to match the single space before `*foo` in my string as the `*` quantifier should match zero or more characters greedily.

Exchanging `\\s` with `[ \t]` or even  `*` (note the space) does not make a difference either.

Why does `\\s*` seem to match zero characters in presence of a space?

Comment: Try removing the first slash in your capture group and see if that helps.

Comment: @LiamFiddler: No change. I also tried to replace `\\s` with `[ \t]` as noted without any difference. Even using only `( *)` as the capture group does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to make sure that the final character group doesn't match space characters.  So you want:

```
struct foo(\\s*)[^*\\s]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regular expression:

```py
(?:struct foo\s*)([^*\s]+)
```

This will return you what comes after the spaces if no asterisk is provided.

Example:
`struct foo *bar` would return nothing.
`struct foo    bar` would return `bar`.

Test and explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/dVeHc3/1

Comment: This works, but I still don't know why my regex, specifically `\s*` doesn't.

Comment: That is because your regex expects zero or more whitespaces after `struct foo`. That matches, and then the part `[^*]` matches the part after as soon as the previous condition met (`struct foo`), but the space behind it got already matched by the part before that, so it matches an empty string. At least, that would be my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

`(\\s*)` is correctly matching zero spaces. The `[^*]` can't match against the `*` in the text, so it should match against the previous character, which is the only available space that `(\\s*)` would have matched against.

Comment: But shouldn't match evaluation proceed from left to right, i.e. the `(\\s*)` should consume as many spaces as possible (greedy) before evaluation of the next token in the regex starts?

Comment: A greedy match will match as much as possible, but it will consume less than everything to make a match. If it didn't do that, then the regex `.*a` would never match anything.

Comment: Sounds like you want your expression to be `struct foo(\\s*)[^*\\s]`

Comment: @Steve: add that as an answer or edit into this answer and I'll accept.